# Modify an existing ASPxGaugeControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

We need to programmatically change the Range value programmatically.

```
 <dx:ASPxGaugeControl ID="SpeedSUM" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="260px" Value="10" Width="417px" style="text-align:center; align-content:center; padding-top:10px" AutoLayout="False">
                                    <Gauges>
                                        <dx:CircularGauge Bounds="0, 0, 413, 258" Name="cGauge1">
                                            <scales>
                                                <dx:ArcScaleComponent ID="QWE" AcceptOrder="0" AppearanceMajorTickmark-BorderBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:White&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceMajorTickmark-ContentBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:White&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceMinorTickmark-BorderBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:White&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceMinorTickmark-ContentBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Tan&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceTickmarkText-Font="Tahoma, 12pt" AppearanceTickmarkText-TextBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Black&quot;/&gt;" Center="125, 165" EndAngle="0" MajorTickCount="6" MajorTickmark-FormatString="{0:F0}" MajorTickmark-ShapeOffset="-5" MajorTickmark-ShapeScale="0.6, 0.8" MajorTickmark-ShapeType="Circular_Style11_4" MajorTickmark-TextOffset="-17" MajorTickmark-TextOrientation="LeftToRight" MaxValue="1000" MinorTickCount="5" MinorTickmark-ShapeOffset="-2.5" MinorTickmark-ShapeScale="0.6, 1" MinorTickmark-ShapeType="Circular_Style11_3" Name="scale1" RadiusX="107" RadiusY="107" StartAngle="-180" Value="10">
                                                    <ranges>
                                                        <dx:ArcScaleRangeWeb AppearanceRange-BorderBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Green&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceRange-BorderWidth="1" AppearanceRange-ContentBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Green&quot;/&gt;" EndValue="1000" Name="Range0" ShapeOffset="11" StartValue="900" />
                                                        <dx:ArcScaleRangeWeb AppearanceRange-BorderBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Red&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceRange-ContentBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Red&quot;/&gt;" EndThickness="11" EndValue="600" Name="Range1" ShapeOffset="11" />
                                                        <dx:ArcScaleRangeWeb AppearanceRange-BorderBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Yellow&quot;/&gt;" AppearanceRange-ContentBrush="&lt;BrushObject Type=&quot;Solid&quot; Data=&quot;Color:Yellow&quot;/&gt;" EndValue="900" Name="Range2" ShapeOffset="11" StartValue="600" />
                                                    </ranges>
                                                </dx:ArcScaleComponent>
                                            </scales>
                                            <backgroundlayers>
                                                <dx:ArcScaleBackgroundLayerComponent AcceptOrder="-1000" ArcScale="" Name="bg1" ScaleCenterPos="0.5, 0.815" ScaleID="scale1" ShapeType="CircularHalf_Style11" Size="250, 154" ZOrder="1000" />
                                            </backgroundlayers>
                                            <needles>
                                                <dx:ArcScaleNeedleComponent AcceptOrder="50" ArcScale="" EndOffset="5" Name="needle1" ScaleID="scale1" ShapeType="CircularFull_Style11" StartOffset="-9.5" ZOrder="-50" />
                                            </needles>
                                        </dx:CircularGauge>
                                        <dx:CircularGauge Bounds="346, 0, 68, 46" Name="Gauge0">
                                        </dx:CircularGauge>
                                    </Gauges>
<LayoutPadding All="0" Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0">

</LayoutPadding>
                      </dx:ASPxGaugeControl>
```

QWE.MaxValue = 1100;

```
    SpeedSUM.Gauges.
```

Comment: *"You need to programmatically change the Range value programmatically"*. No I don't. Now, could you please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of your specific issue?

Comment: BTW, perhaps consider formatting your code so that we don't have to scroll miles to the right to see everything. Horizontal scrolling is sometimes necessary but should be avoided if at all possible, as it is a detriment to comfortable reading. That means avoiding loads of useless leading whitespace - only include what is required for proper indenting - and avoiding long lines when they can be wrapped or, in this case, attributes stacked vertically. If you would like us to volunteer our time to help you, you should take the time to do what you can to help us.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I figured it out myself.

```
  QWE.BeginUpdate();
        // Range 1
        ArcScaleRangeWeb range1 = new ArcScaleRangeWeb();
        range1.AppearanceRange.ContentBrush = new SolidBrushObject(Color.Yellow);
        range1.StartValue = 600;
        range1.EndValue = 800;
        range1.ShapeOffset = 11;
        // Range 2
        ArcScaleRangeWeb range2 = new ArcScaleRangeWeb();
        range2.AppearanceRange.ContentBrush = new SolidBrushObject(Color.Red);
        range2.StartValue = 0;
        range2.EndValue = 600;
        range2.ShapeOffset = 11;
        // Range 2
        ArcScaleRangeWeb range3 = new ArcScaleRangeWeb();
        range3.AppearanceRange.ContentBrush = new SolidBrushObject(Color.Green);
        range3.StartValue = 800;
        range3.EndValue = 1100;
        range3.ShapeOffset = 11;
        // Add the ranges to the scale.
        QWE.Ranges.AddRange(new ArcScaleRangeWeb[] { range1, range2, range3 });
        QWE.EndUpdate();
```